# How can I perform webscrapyn with scrapy and splash python

Tags: python, web-scraping, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to perform scraping on a supermarket website, but I can't get the object used to search for its class. I am using scrapy with splash because the website has javascript

i am using this code

```
function main(splash)
    local url = splash.args.url
    assert(splash:go(url))
  
    splash:set_viewport_full()
     
    search_input = assert(splash:select('.ais-SearchBox-input'))        
    search_input.focus()
    search_input:send_text("fideos")

    assert(splash:wait(3))

    return {
        html = splash:html(),
        png = splash:png(),
    }
  end
```

but i get the following error

```
Error happened while executing Lua script

Lua error: [string " function main(splash) ..."]:7: assertion failed!

{
    "error": 400,
    "type": "ScriptError",
    "description": 
"Error happened while executing Lua script",
    "info": {
        "source": "[string \" function main(splash)\r...\"]",
        "line_number": 7,
        "error": "assertion failed!",
        "type": "LUA_ERROR",
        "message": "Lua error: [string \" function main(splash)\r...\"]:7: assertion failed!"
    }
}
```

What will be the correct way to get the element found in the ais-SearchBox-input class?
thanks

url: https://www.lider.cl/supermercado

html found on the page ( `<input type="search" placeholder="¿Qué estás buscando?" maxlength="512" class="ais-SearchBox-input" value="">`)

```
 <form class="ais-SearchBox-form" role="search">

<input type="search" placeholder="¿Qué estás buscando?" maxlength="512" class="ais-SearchBox-input" value="">

<button type="submit" title="Submit your search query." class="ais-SearchBox-submit search-input-icons"><svg class="ais-SearchBox-submitIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><path d="M26.804 29.01c-2.832 2.34-6.465 3.746-10.426 3.746C7.333 32.756 0 25.424 0 16.378 0 7.333 7.333 0 16.378 0c9.046 0 16.378 7.333 16.378 16.378 0 3.96-1.406 7.594-3.746 10.426l10.534 10.534c.607.607.61 1.59-.004 2.202-.61.61-1.597.61-2.202.004L26.804 29.01zm-10.426.627c7.323 0 13.26-5.936 13.26-13.26 0-7.32-5.937-13.257-13.26-13.257C9.056 3.12 3.12 9.056 3.12 16.378c0 7.323 5.936 13.26 13.258 13.26z"></path></svg></button><button type="button" title="Clear the search query." class="ais-SearchBox-reset search-input-icons" hidden=""><svg class="ais-SearchBox-resetIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="10" height="10"><path d="M8.114 10L.944 2.83 0 1.885 1.886 0l.943.943L10 8.113l7.17-7.17.944-.943L20 1.886l-.943.943-7.17 7.17 7.17 7.17.943.944L18.114 20l-.943-.943-7.17-7.17-7.17 7.17-.944.943L0 18.114l.943-.943L8.113 10z"></path></svg></button><span class="ais-SearchBox-loadingIndicator" hidden=""><svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 38 38" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="#444" class="ais-SearchBox-loadingIcon"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g transform="translate(1 1)" stroke-width="2"><circle stroke-opacity=".5" cx="18" cy="18" r="18"></circle><path d="M36 18c0-9.94-8.06-18-18-18" transform="rotate(215.328 18 18)"><animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 18 18" to="360 18 18" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform></path></g></g></svg></span></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe checking for the value of those calls, since both `:go` and `:wait` can give you a reason for failure.
If select is the blocking point, maybe look the value of `splash.args.url`.

```lua
function main(splash)
    local function check(ok, reason)
        if not ok then
            reason = reason or "select failed to retrieve the element"
            print(reason)
            os.exit(1)
        end
        return ok
    end

    local url = splash.args.url
    check(splash:go(url))

    splash:set_viewport_full()

    search_input = check(splash:select(".ais-SearchBox-input"))
    search_input.focus()
    search_input:send_text("fideos")

    check(splash:wait(3))

    return {
        html = splash:html(),
        png = splash:png(),
    }
end
```